# Scroll to the top of the list in vue scrollable list (v-auto-complete)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scroll, vuetify.js

I have a scrollable list that i can select multiple items from. I want to programmatically implement a way to scroll to top of the list every time i change the search input.

Desired behavior: For example; when i type 'b' in the search list, and scroll down, then if i type 'e' again i would like it to scroll to the very top

Here's a code example showing what i would like to do, I've tried two different methods. I have tried two different approaches in the code below where i utilize scrollTop feature of the html Element and goTo function from vuetify but none of them worked.

Code demo-> https://www.codeply.com/p/ZGBNEHW7YS

In case the demo expires, the actual code;

```
<div id="app">
    <v-app>
        <v-main class="py-3 px-5">
            <h1 class="teal--text">AutoComplete Infinite Scroll Example</h1>
            <v-autocomplete 
                id="autoComplete"
                ref="autoComplete"
                v-model="selected"
                :items="beers" 
                item-text="name" 
                item-value="id" 
                :search-input.sync="search"
                label="Search the beers.."
                return-object
                multiple
                autocomplete="off"
                >
                <template v-slot:append-item>
                  <div v-intersect="onIntersect" class="pa-4 teal--text">
                     Loading more items ...
                  </div>
                </template>
            </v-autocomplete>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
```

---

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data() {
        return {
          search:'',
          beers: [],
          selected: null,
          perPage: 30,
          page: 1,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getBeers() {
            console.log('page', this.page)
            const apiUrl = `https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?page=${this.page}&per_page=${this.perPage}`
            axios.get(apiUrl)
                .then(response => {
                  this.beers = [
                      ...this.beers,
                      ...response.data
                  ]
            })
        },
        onIntersect () {
            console.log('load more...')
            this.page += 1
            this.getBeers()
        },
    },
    watch:{
        search:function(){
         //first method
          let myId=document.getElementById('autoComplete')
          if(myId){
            myId.scrollTop = 0
    
          }
          
          //second method with ref  and vuetify goto
          this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.$vuetify.goTo(this.$refs.autoComplete) 
          })
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.getBeers()
    }
})
```

Comment: you need to get the position of that item and scroll the scrollable container to that coordinate e. g `scrollableContainer.scrollTop = myIdElement.offsetTop`

Comment: I have updated my code to do that but it still didn't work. @zergski

Comment: The problem is element doesn't exist when i search something new @zergski. I have updated the code in the demo if you want to take a look

Comment: you need to get the correct DOM element references. both for the scrollable list container and the searched items. and the names I used were only example names

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this (see demo in full page)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
 data: () => ({
    beers: [],
          selected: null,
          perPage: 30,
          page: 1,
  
  }),
     created() {
        this.getBeers()
    },
  methods: {
    goToTop(){
      this.beers = [];
      this.page = 1;
      this.getBeers();
    },
       getBeers() {
            console.log('page', this.page)
            const apiUrl = `https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?page=${this.page}&per_page=${this.perPage}`
            axios.get(apiUrl)
                .then(response => {
                  this.beers = [
                      ...this.beers,
                      ...response.data
                  ]
            })
        },
            onIntersect () {
            this.page += 1
            this.getBeers()
        },
  },
})
```

```css
.scroll-to-top {
  position:sticky;
  bottom:8px;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content :right;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.24.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>


 <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-row
          align="center"
        >
          <v-col cols="12">
            <v-autocomplete 
                v-model="selected"
                :items="beers" 
                item-text="name" 
                item-value="id" 
                label="Search da beers.."
                return-object
                autocomplete="off"
                >
              
          
               <template v-slot:append-item>
                 <div v-intersect="onIntersect" class="pa-4 teal--text">
                     Loading more items ...
                  </div>
                            <div class="text-right pr-4 scroll-to-top">
                              <v-btn
                                color="primary"
                                small
                                class="align-right"
                                @click="goToTop"
                              >
                                 Go to top
                              </v-btn>
                            </div>
                          </template>
            </v-autocomplete>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The cursor still remains in the same place when i type something in search box. And you changed the code where it needs to have multiple property so that this scroll function would make sense with scrolling

Comment: this covers the base functionality.. now you can extend it as you want... you can call the function when any change happens in search...

Comment: The v-btn that you created is not visible in the UI. Not sure how i can call it, basic functionality doesn't work on my end

Comment: look at my code and compare with your code

Comment: put scroll button inside <template v-slot:append-item> and on button click call goToTop method

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i solved by using zergski's example.

Casting was required because of typescript.

```
scrollTop(): void {
  let scrollList = document.querySelector('.v-autocomplete__content')

  let firstElement = document.querySelector('.company-item-name') as HTMLElement

  if (scrollList && firstElement && firstElement.offsetTop) {
    scrollList.scrollTop = firstElement.offsetTop
  }
},
```